# Drag and drop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've been trying to get my drag and drop to work, can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I basically can't drop the images to the body image.

I tried  `JSLint/JSHint` to clean my code but that didn't help me get it to work.

Can someone please help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <style>
            div#OuterDiv {
                border: 1px solid black;
                position: relative;
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
                background-color: gray;
                color: white;
                font: times new roman;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script language="text/javascript">
            'use strict';
            var ie4 = ua.indexOf("MSIE 4.0");

            var curElement;
            window.onload = opening;
            document.ondragstart = doDragStart;
            document.onmousedown = doMouseDown;
            document.onmousemove = doMouseMove;
            document.onmouseup = new Function("curElement=null");


            function opening() {
                if (ie4Final) {
                    if (body.style.display === "none") {
                        OuterDiv.filters[0].Apply();
                        body.style.display = "";
                        OuterDiv.filters[0].Play();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (betaVer >= 2) {
                        body.style.display = "";
                    }
                }
            }

            function doMouseMove() {
                var newleft = 0,
                    newTop = 0;
                if ((event.button === 1) && (curElement !== null)) {
                    newleft = window.event.x - tx;
                    if (newleft < 0) {
                        newleft = 0;
                        if (newleft + curElement.width > document.all.OuterDiv.offsetWidth) newleft = document.all.OuterDiv.offsetWidth - curElement.offsetWidth;
                        curElement.style.pixelLeft = newleft;
                        newtop = event.clientY - document.all.OuterDiv.offsetTop - (curElement.offsetHeight / 2);
                        if (newtop < 0) {
                            newtop = 0;
                            if (newtop + curElement.height > document.all.OuterDiv.offsetHeight) newtop = window.event.y - ty;
                            curElement.style.pixelTop = newtop;
                            event.returnValue = false;
                            event.cancelBubble = true;
                        }
                    }

                    function doDragStart() {
                        if ("IMG" === event.srcElement.tagName) {
                            event.returnValue = false;
                        }
                    }


                    function doMouseDown() {
                        if ((event.button === 1) && (event.srcElement.tagName === "img")) {
                            tx = window.event.x - event.srcElement.style.pixelLeft;
                            ty = window.event.y - event.srcElement.style.pixelTop;
                            curElement = event.srcElement;
                        }
                    }
        </script>
        <script FOR="body" event="onMouseDown">
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        </script>
        <div id="OuterDiv">
            <h1><Center>Drag and Drop - potato head</center></h1>

            <img ID="body" style="position:absolute;left:10;top:190;z-index:19;" src="BODY.GIF" />
            <img ID="ear1" style="position:absolute;left:60;top:70;z-index:19;" src="EAR1.GIF" />
            <img ID="ear2" style="position:absolute;left120;top:70;z-index:19;" src="EAR2.GIF">
            <img ID="glasses4" style="position:absolute;left:120;top:70;z-index:19;" src="GLASSES4.GIF" />
            <img ID="mouth1" style="position:absolute;left:290;top:70;z-index:19;" src="MOUTH1.GIF" />
            <img ID="nose1" style="position:absolute;left:450;top:70;z-index:19;" src="NOSE1.GIF" />
            <img ID="eyes4" style="position:absolute;left:510;top:70;z-index:19;" src="EYES4.GIF" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to do this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
am I wrong?

Comment: No you're right, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Well, then is that a good solution for you? it seems much simpler than all your code and is supported by all major browsers.

Comment: You need to use other event types: ondragover and ondrop to make this work.

Comment: im sorry, im new to this. when you say other, what do you mean? instead of which event?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need not have to include head, body, title tags in sample code unless the question specifically needs them (in this case, I don't think they do). While it is good that you have provided your code, it is also good to provide as much information as you can in the question. Do you get any errors in console? Is the problem happening in any specific case/browsers etc. Technology names are generally not required in title (since they are part of tags).

Answer (score 0):

You may try next code:

```js
function ondrop(ev){
  var FieldClone=document.getElementByID("textField").clone(true);
  ev.target.appendChild(FieldClone);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textField" value="Drop me" name="" draggable="true">
    <div id="sec_drop" ondrop="drop(event)"style="width: 500px;height: 370px;"ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
```